# QuerySyntaxException : Query to calculate total monthly count from a table and sum from another related table

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

What I want to do is display totals when a particular branch is selected from a dropdown . A relationship has been created between the Investment , Customer and User class

**Repository**

```
@Query("select sum(investment.principal) as totalBranchPrincipal, count (customer_id) as totalBranchCustomers, "
            + "sum(investment.maturityInterest) as totalBranchMaturityInterest,"
            + "from Investment investment join investment.customer_id.marketer marketer where marketer.branch = :branch ")
    List<?> getBranchReporting(Branch branch);
```

**This is the service**

```
public List<?> getTotalMonthlyBranchData(Branch branch){
    List<?> monthlyBranchData = investmentRepository.getBranchReporting(branch);
    return monthlyBranchData;
    }
```

**This is the Controller**

```
   @GetMapping(value="/branchMonthlyReporting/{id}")
    public List<?> getBranchMonthlyReport(Branch branch) {
    return investmentService.getTotalMonthlyBranchData(branch);
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are using an ORM such as hibernate. In which case you need to define 'branch' as a parameter, so that it can be bound to ':branch'

Comment: @jr593 I have passed the branch object as parameter in the repository . Can  I get an example of what you are talking about ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my queries I write this as the method signature
List<?> getBranchReporting(@Param("branch")Branch branch);